# Get images from folder(s), merging two images and then output variant image(s) into new folder w/ unique file names

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have two folders, one containing **shirts** with different colors and the other with **logos**.

I'm trying to take the images contained in the shirts folder and storing them into an array. I kinda figured how to "store" them using the tkinter module. But kinda confused. I would like to be able to do the same with the logos. Once stored in the array, I want to fetch the images and merge them into every possible image combination for each shirt/logo color **OR** better yet, specify which colors should have which logos depending on color.

Within the merging process, I want it to resize the shirt image and logo image to a standard size and place the logo image in a specific spot on the shirt image.

Once all that's done, I want to export the new images into a folder with unique names (thinking of a loop that adds shirt_n.jpg, n = 1,2,3 etc.)

I tried looking it all up and I do find pieces of what I want but I can't figure out how to put it together to work.

**EDIT:** I kinda figured out HOW to get the outcome I want but as you can see below the code below is very simple and not optimized. Which I have no idea how to optimize to compress it into less lines of code.

```
# python imports
import os
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import Image

Tk().withdraw()
imFile = askopenfilename()

print("What shade is the shirt? Dark or Light?")
respShade = input()
print("What's the logo location? Right or Left?:")
respLocation = input()
print("Color abriv. name?")
respName = input()

shirt = Image.open(imFile)
shirt_01 = shirt.resize((1200, 1800))
shirt_02 = shirt.resize((1200, 1800))
shirt_03 = shirt.resize((1200, 1800))

# For Dark Apparel
if "ark" in respShade:
    logo_hfwl = Image.open("images/logos/randazzo/hfox-wht.png")
    logo_hfwl = logo_hfwl.resize((150, 80))
    logo_hrtw = Image.open("images/logos/randazzo/htld-wht.png")
    logo_hrtw = logo_hrtw.resize((150, 80))
    logo3_rzwl = Image.open("images/logos/randazzo/rand-wht.png")
    logo3_rzwl = logo3_rzwl.resize((150, 80))

    if "lef" in respLocation:
        shirt_01.paste(logo_hfwl, (660, 660), logo_hfwl)
        shirt_02.paste(logo_hrtw, (660, 660), logo_hrtw)
        shirt_03.paste(logo3_rzwl, (660, 660), logo3_rzwl)

    elif "rig" in respLocation:
        shirt_01.paste(logo_hfwl, (410, 660), logo_hfwl)
        shirt_02.paste(logo_hrtw, (410, 660), logo_hrtw)
        shirt_03.paste(logo3_rzwl, (410, 660), logo3_rzwl)

    shirt_01.save('images/final/' + respName + '-hfwl.jpg')
    shirt_02.save('images/final/' + respName + '-hrtw.jpg')
    shirt_03.save('images/final/' + respName + '-rwl.jpg')

# For Light Apparel

if "ght" in respShade:
    logo_hfwl = Image.open("images/logos/randazzo/hfox.png")
    logo_hfwl = logo_hfwl.resize((150, 80))
    logo_hrtw = Image.open("images/logos/randazzo/htld.png")
    logo_hrtw = logo_hrtw.resize((150, 80))
    logo3_rzwl = Image.open("images/logos/randazzo/rand.png")
    logo3_rzwl = logo3_rzwl.resize((150, 80))

    if "lef" in respLocation:
        shirt_01.paste(logo_hfwl, (660, 660), logo_hfwl)
        shirt_02.paste(logo_hrtw, (660, 660), logo_hrtw)
        shirt_03.paste(logo3_rzwl, (660, 660), logo3_rzwl)

    elif "rig" in respLocation:
        shirt_01.paste(logo_hfwl, (410, 660), logo_hfwl)
        shirt_02.paste(logo_hrtw, (410, 660), logo_hrtw)
        shirt_03.paste(logo3_rzwl, (410, 660), logo3_rzwl)

    shirt_01.save('images/final/' + respName + '-hfwl.jpg')
    shirt_02.save('images/final/' + respName + '-hrtw.jpg')
    shirt_03.save('images/final/' + respName + '-rwl.jpg')

# shirt.save('images/final/change_me.jpg')
path = "images/final/"
path = os.path.realpath(path)
os.startfile(path)
```

Also, I tried looking up how to save them into a folder with unique names. Couldn't really find anything really straight forward. If you could explain the thought process behind your solution, that would help me understand! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, but this question is too broad. It contains multiple questions, it's not even absolutely clear where the problem is exactly, and therefore it is not a good fit for this site. Please break down the question into smaller steps and ask multiple more focused questions, each with a clear statement of what you want to achieve. A bounty will not help much here. For example, if the only problem was how to create unique file names, then surely [color]_[logo] would be sufficient.

Comment: Do you have to use tkinter? I would suggest you to have a look at the OpenCV library: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html

Comment: What is wrong with the code you are using. Do you only need help with storing it in a new location after the copying is done?

Comment: @CoolCloud I can't figure out how to store multiple images to call within the code, combine them into every possible combination, then save them as multiple images with different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I suggest to organize the images as follows:

```
├── logos      // all logos
├── shirts
│   ├── light  // light colored shirts 
│   └── dark   // dark colored shirts
├── final
│   ├── right  // all shirts with each logo on the right
│   └── left   // all shirts with each logo on the left
```

Then we need to define a function to read all images in a directory, without the need to get user input. That is why I think we don't need tkinter at all

```
def getImages(searchDir):
    """
    Returns a list with the paths of all images found in the given path
    """

    imagesPaths = []

    for root, directories, files in walk(searchDir):
        for file in files:
            if '.jpg' in file or '.png' in file:
                imagesPaths.append(path.join(root, file))
    
    print("Found images in '{}' = {}".format(searchDir, len(imagesPaths)))
    return imagesPaths
```

Now the most important function is the one which merges the logo in ".png" format over a shirt in ".jpeg" format. This function has three parts:

- Part 1: Open both images then resize both of them to the desired height and width.
- Part 2: Paste the logo over the shirt (we need a trick to do that so we change the color format into RGBA)
- Part3: Get the name of both files, then "glue" them together. You are free to name your images as you like, so feel free to change this step as much as you need.

This is the body of such a function:

```
def addLogo(shirtPath, logoPath, shift=(0,0), outPath="final"):    
"""
    Takes a background image and a foreground image add merge them.
    The foreground image can be scaled and be rotated. It can also 
    be put at an aribttatry location (x,y). 
    """
    
    img1 = Image.open(shirtPath).convert('RGBA')
    img2 = Image.open(logoPath).convert('RGBA')
    
    img1 = img1.resize((1200, 1800))
    img2 = img2.resize((150, 80))

    # paste img2 on top of img1
    shift1 = (0, 0)
    shift2 = shift
    blended = Image.new('RGBA', size=(1200, 1800), color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
    blended.paste(img1, shift1)
    blended.paste(img2, shift2, img2)

    # Save the image with a name combinig both images names
    name1 = getNameWithoutExtension(shirtPath)
    name2 = getNameWithoutExtension(logoPath)
    blended = blended.convert("RGB")
    blended.save("{}/{}_{}.jpg".format(outPath, name2, name1))
```

This is a sample of the result I got inside the "final/left" folder. I had two shirts and three logos, so the result was six pictures.

[image]

Finally, this is the whole code

```
# python imports
from os import walk, path, rename, mkdir
from PIL import Image

# This is a generic function which gets all paths of images
def getImages(searchDir):
    """
    Returns a list with the paths of all images found in the given path
    """

    imagesPaths = []

    for root, directories, files in walk(searchDir):
        for file in files:
            if '.jpg' in file or '.png' in file:
                imagesPaths.append(path.join(root, file))
    
    print("Found images in '{}' = {}".format(searchDir, len(imagesPaths)))
    return imagesPaths


def getNameWithoutExtension(imagePath):
        name = path.basename(imagePath)
        return path.splitext(name)[0]

def addLogo(shirtPath, logoPath, shift=(0,0), outPath="final"):
    """
    Takes a background image and a foreground image add merge them.
    The foreground image can be scaled and be rotated. It can also 
    be put at an aribttatry location (x,y). 
    """
    
    img1 = Image.open(shirtPath).convert('RGBA')
    img2 = Image.open(logoPath).convert('RGBA')
    
    img1 = img1.resize((1200, 1800))
    img2 = img2.resize((150, 80))

    # paste img2 on top of img1
    shift1 = (0, 0)
    shift2 = shift
    blended = Image.new('RGBA', size=(1200, 1800), color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
    blended.paste(img1, shift1)
    blended.paste(img2, shift2, img2)

    # Save the image with a name combinig both images names
    name1 = getNameWithoutExtension(shirtPath)
    name2 = getNameWithoutExtension(logoPath)
    blended = blended.convert("RGB")
    blended.save("{}/{}_{}.jpg".format(outPath, name2, name1))


# Load all logo files
logos_array = getImages("logos")

# Load all light shirts
light_shirts_array = getImages("shirts/light")

#Load all dark shirts
dark_shirts_array = getImages("shirts/dark")

# Loop over light shirts and add each logo to each of them
for shirt in light_shirts_array:
    for logo in logos_array:

        # Paste on the left
        addLogo(shirt, logo, (410, 660), "final/left")
        
        # Paste on the right
        addLogo(shirt, logo, (660, 660), "final/right")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search through the files in a directory by using the os.listdir() function. Try adding this to your code.

```
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk
import os

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
path = filedialog.askdirectory(master=root)

imported_images = []
for file in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
    imported_images.append(file_path)

# An easier, one-liner for doing this is by the use of list comprehension.
# imported_images = [os.path.join(path, file) for file in os.listdir(path)]

# imported_images is now a list of all the file paths in the specified directory.
```

I believe using the askdirectory function is an easier way than pasting it in.